# css navbar hover drop down

Tags: html, css, hover

I am looking to make a navbar menu that drops down when hovering over a specific navbar li.

My navbar looked and worked fine until I tried to get a hover drop down to work. Specifically this is what I am looking for:hover over "work" and get a drop down menu of "videos" and "photography". I don't think that I am nesting anything wrong, so I figure that it is the CSS that is wrong. I have tried a few different suggestions, but nothing has worked.

Side note: I recently gave the nav items the id of "menu". I had it so that the current page on the nav would be a certain darker color and when the current page nav was hovered it would stay that same color. This worked before I changed to id to "menu" (before it was "nav ul li"). Now when you hover, it changes the color. what made this change happen?

```css
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
ul, ol, dl {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
ul#menu {
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
background-color: #bac9a9;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
}
ul#menu:after {
content:"";
background-image: url("../images/navbar-shadow-green.jpg");
height: 8px;
width: 100%;
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
margin-top: 4px;
}
ul#menu li {
display: inline;
}
ul#menu li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #f3ffcf;
font-size: 22px;
padding: 10px 25px;
margin: 0 -2px;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
background-color: #b2c1a2;
}
a.selected-page, a.selected-page:hover {
background-color: #a6b396;
}
li#sub ul {
display: none;
}
ul#menu li#sub:hover ul {
display: block;
}

<nav>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="selected-page">about</a>
    </li>
    <li id="sub"><a href="#">work</a>
    </li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">videos</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">photography</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcJN5/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have got the nesting wrong. You want the list which is revealed when you roll over the work list item to be a child of that list item. Try updating your HTML / CSS as follows (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcJN5/3/)):

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="selected-page">about</a>
        </li>
        <li id="sub">
            <a href="#">work</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">videos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">photography</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul, ol, dl {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #bac9a9;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul#menu:after {
    content:"";
    background-image: url("../images/navbar-shadow-green.jpg");
    height: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
}
ul#menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f3ffcf;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    margin: 0 -2px;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #b2c1a2;
}
a.selected-page, a.selected-page:hover {
    background-color: #a6b396;
}
li#sub ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px; left: 115px;
    background-color: #b2c1a2;
}
li#sub ul li {
    display: block;
}
ul#menu li#sub:hover ul {
    display: block;

}
```

Comment: Well this definitely helps. However the hover is still messed up. How can I get it so that "videos" and "photography" are stacked vertically and show up below "work"? Forgive me if this is obvious, I am very new to this.